# Regex for selecting the double quotes inside the curly braces while ignoring the ones outside

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I asked a question yesterday on the same which was not detailed enough. Also the suggestion provided looked like solving my problem. But there are edge cases. So I am reposting. But this time with more details.

Here is the string:

```
"2019/03/19","LegacyApp","{""Id"":""345-dg8"",{""Hello"",""This""},""Fake"":""Sym""}","","","(null)","",
```

And I want to match the quotes as highlighted below.

[image: To match]

<strike>The regex I have got till now is `(?:[^{]+):(.*)$`
But it is selecting till the end. And in two groups. Any ideas will be much appreciated.</strike>

**Update:** Now I am able to select the part between the curly braces. `{(?:\n|.)*}`. Somehow need to match the double quotes in that selection.

**Update**: This is working but I am not sure about performance of this guy.

```
""(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])|""(?=})|""(?=:)|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])""
```

Specially since this regex will be running against each one of the million logs getting ingested.

**Note:** I am trying to run it in Elasticsearch. As per them, The Lucene regular expression engine is not Perl-compatible but supports a smaller range of operators.

Comment: Is nesting limited to 1 level (as per your example)? If not, you’ll need recursive support, which AFIAK isn’t supported by ES.

Comment: There are so many logs. As of now I will say let us assume that nesting is limited to 1. Sorry for not being able to give a definate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

I would like you to use 'offsets' that every regex library in languages provides. It lets you know locations of matched texts.

First, use this regex to find out locations where brackets are.

```
{.+}
```

Let's say that the offsets of the result is from 3 to 21.

And then, use this simple regex.

```
""
```

The offsets of the result return an array like ([5,6], [12,13]...)

Finally, use 'for' clause to pick out double quotations inside brackets.

The other method is the following regex.

```
(?<={|{[^}]|{[^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}]|{[^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}][^}])""|""(?=[^{]*})
```

[image]

Comment: Can you have a look at the one I added to the question. Any edge cases there?

Comment: ""(?=[^",])|""(?=})|""(?=:)|(?<=[^",])""  is better as there can be not only alpha-numeric values but other characters.